# Failing to display Image from Django admin

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to view/display the image that I have uploaded in the products model. [product html to view whats in produvt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksxgc.jpg).

[This is the product model code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnpZj.jpg).

[This is what the i get when I run code  view products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOT4u.jpg).

This below is the views.py code:

```
def ProductDetailtListView(request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
#instance = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)#id
instance = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
context = {


    'object': instance
}

return render(request, 'MainApp/productDetail.html', context)
```

This below is the models.py code:

```
class Product(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
description = models.TextField()
price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=39.99)
image = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null= True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

This the productDetailListView.html page:

```
{% load static %}
{{ object.title }} <br/>
{{ object.description }} <br/>
{{ object.image.url }}
<img src="{{ object.image.urls }}" class='img-fluid'/>
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode Did not dv, but please copy the code into the question, not *images* of the code fragments.

Comment: I placed the code now

Comment: You made a typo: it is `.url` not `.urls`.

Comment: I fixed that typo however now it shows that the is an Image to be rendered but does not display the Image.

Comment: did you add the media files to the `urlpatterns`?

Comment: <img src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt='cant parse image'/>

Comment: When I add the alt the code renders the alt

Comment: This is my urls below:

```urlpatterns = [


    url(r'^$', home_page),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact_page),
    url(r'^login/$', login_page),
    url(r'^register/$', register_page),
    url(r'^products/$', ProductListView),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)$', ProductDetailtListView),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]```

Comment: How do I add media files never worked with them